# Python Dictionary : '{num} = {title}'.format(**dict(num=7, title='Strings'))

Tags: python-3.x

I have doubt regarding this specific line

```
'{num} = {title}'.format(**dict(num=7, title='Strings'))

'7 = Strings'
```

I couldn't understand how **dict is working here. if anybody could help me on this.

Comment: The `**` is the syntax for mapping unpacking.  This code is identical to `'{num} = {title}'.format(num=7, title='Strings')`

Comment: thank you , where can I read about this more. 
thank you for your time.

Comment: The place to start is probably [PEP 448](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0448/), where it was introduced